# Creating grid with statistics of merged shapefiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, area, clustering, statistics, vector-grid

I operate with QGIS. I have to split the shape files of the buildings and the roads of a city into a grid of 500x500m per square and into each square I have to obtain the total free area, the total area of the buildings and of the roads.

Can anyone help me?

I've tried to create a vector grid and merging the shape files with the intersection function but I've only multiplied the geometries.

Comment: Are your buildings and roads both polygons?

Comment: No, only the buildings, roads are just lines)

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this before. Assuming your road layer is a line as @SaultDon asked then you will need to use the **buffer** tool (use a very low value for buffer distance if you don't know the width of the road). If it's already a polygon then great! Now, with your 500x500m grid, use **clip** for both your building and the road(buffer) layers. The output of these are:

- A building layer on a 500x500m grid. Open the *Field Calculator* and calculate a new field using the expression `$area` to find the **total area of the buildings** in each square. Create another field using the expression `(500 * 500) - "total_area_for_buildings_field"` to find the **total free area**.
- A road(buffer) layer on a 500x500m grid. Similar to above, open the *Field Calculator* and calculate a new field using the expression `$area` to find the **total area of the roads** in each square. Create another field using the expression `(500 * 500) - "total_area_for_roads_field"` to find the **total free area**.

Comment: I'm trying this way. But how can it possible calculate the road's area if the roads are just lines?

Comment: You can either use the **Lines to polygon tool** (_Vector_ > _Geometry Tools_ > _Lines to polygon_) or use the **buffer** tool (_Vector_ > _Geoprocessing Tools_ > _Buffer(s)_).